# iOS - GCD groups and significant UI delay on finish

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am using GCD to run some code in the background. The operation is finished in a few seconds and in the end "DONE" is printed as expected. However I have to wait ~5 seconds (simulator) to ~1 minute (device) for hud to hide. What might be the reason for such a long delay? I know the processing is finished because I can see the result for every element.

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeAnnularDeterminate;
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0);

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithArray: [codePositions allKeys]];
for (id key in keys) {
    if (key == nil)
        continue;
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        ... // processing
        NSLog(@"Element %d result: %@", element.id, element.result);
        hud.progress += 1.0/96.0;
    });
}
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"DONE");
    [hud hide:YES];
});
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to perform all UI updates on the main thread. Update your code as follows:

```
for (id key in keys) {
    if (key == nil)
        continue;
    dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
        ... // processing
        NSLog(@"Element %d result: %@", element.id, element.result);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            hud.progress += 1.0/96.0;
        });
    });
}
dispatch_group_notify(group, queue, ^{
    NSLog(@"DONE");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [hud hide:YES];
    });
});
```